# Reshape correlation matrix to be stacked by column pairs

Tags: r, matrix, reshape

In R, I use `cov2cor()` to calculate a correlation matrix like:

```
  A,B,C,...
A 1,0.5,0.2,...
B 0.5,1,0.4,...
C 0.2,0.4,1,...
...
```

How can I reshape the matrix so that the columns are stacked in rows like:

```
X,Y,Correlation
A,B,0.5,
A,C,0.2,
...
B,C,0.4,
...
```

Remind that `A,A`s are excluded, and `A,B` `B,A` are treated as duplicates so that one are excluded.

Is there an easy way to implement this?

Comment: not sure how to accept your edit suggestion, so manually updated my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The functions that you need are:

[lower.tri {base}](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/lower.tri.html) : This will allow you to take the correlation matrix and set the upper/lower triangle to NAs as well as exclude the diagonal. This will take care of the duplicate corr values i.e.,only one of these will be retained. cor(A,C)=cor(C,A)

[melt{reshape2}](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf): This will take the lower/upper triangle and melt it into a table with only three columns. The 3rd column will have the correlation between variable in col1 & col2.

[is.na{Matrix}](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/is.na-methods.html): Use this to remove rows where the 3rd column is `NA`.

**Update:** @KunRen has suggesed [`na.omit{base}`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/na.fail.html)as a better alternative to `is.na` which I agree with.

A sample solution would be like the following:

```
system.time(correlations<-cor(mydata,use="pairwise.complete.obs"))#get correlation matrix
upperTriangle<-upper.tri(correlations, diag=F) #turn into a upper triangle
correlations.upperTriangle<-correlations #take a copy of the original cor-mat
correlations.upperTriangle[!upperTriangle]<-NA#set everything not in upper triangle o NA
correlations_melted<-na.omit(melt(correlations.upperTriangle, value.name ="correlationCoef")) #use melt to reshape the matrix into triplets, na.omit to get rid of the NA rows
colnames(correlations_melted)<-c("X1", "X2", "correlation")
```